# Current option "selected" based on URL Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried looking for a solution around here, but nothing is working, so I'm posting one here. Sorry if it exists already.

I have an option list with values being added using PHP (Twig) like so:

```
      <select class='form-control input-sm leader-select' name='leader_select' id='leader-select' style="height:42px;width:115%;">
        <option selected disabled>Leaders</option>
          {% for leader in leader_list %}
            <option id='{{ leader.mold_maker }}' class="leader-options" value='{{ leader.mold_maker }}'>{{ leader.mold_maker }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
      </select>
```

Which pulls each leader name (first and last) from database and displays them as a select box.

I'm trying to make it so that when one is selected it shows up on the next page with that name already selected.

If a leader is selected the URL looks like this: http://example.com/page?leader=First%20Last

And I'm pulling the name from URL like so:

```
var leader_param = GetURLParameter('leader');
```

with some other code at before that to separate the link, when I alert() leader_param i get "First%20Last". So I know that part works 100%.

Now, when trying to get the currently selected leader I figure the best way would be compare the URL name to the value in the option list. From what I've read, the closest thing I have is this:

```
  if (typeof leader_param != 'undefined') {
    $("select[name='leader_select']").val(leader_param);
  }
```

But all that does is make the first option the selected one. I'm pretty stuck here and would really appreciate any help.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I don't think String `"First%20Last"` is equal to `"First Last"`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you are doing the decoding of param:

```
var leader_param = decodeURIComponent( GetURLParameter('leader') );
```

It will convert `First%20Last` to `First Last` and you `value` attribute of you `<option>`s are having value like second one, not first one.

[see: decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: This solved it! Thank you very much! I just put the decodeURIComponent as the first line of the if statement and it's working perfectly. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("yourSelect").find(" option[value='" + leader_param + "']").prop('selected', 'selected');
```

or

```
$("yourSelect").find(" option[value='" + decodeURIComponent(leader_param) + "']").prop('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the correct value in variable `leader_param`, You can set the corresponding option as selected using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) method like:

```
if (leader_param) {
  $("select[name='leader_select']").find("option[value='"+leader_param+"']").prop("selected",true);
}
```